# Discourage linebreaks before/after math

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I would like to discourage linebreaks right before and after inline math displays, such that

```
now let $f$ be the function that connects
```

acts similar to

```
now let~$f$~be the function that connects
```

It's not important to me that the behaviour is exactly the same - in fact, I only want to discourage linebreaks at these locations, not necessarily completely forbid them. I have a long document with lots of inline math (as a matter of fact, my Masters thesis) and I would like to see things like

```
                      ... now let f
be the function that connects ...
```

and

```
                        ... now let
f be the function that connects ...
```

less often, without having to edit every single occurence (which would be several hundred manual edits).

Comment: Do you have cases of inline math starting or ending a sentence? If so, do you  want to prevent line breaks involving inline math expressions across sentences?

Comment: This would have been a lot easier if you'd have used the latex `\(`  `\)` syntax, one reason for introducing that is it is then trivial to redefine the commands for special affects, eg define `\(` to include `\nolinebreak[3]` or whatever.

Comment: Inline math (almost) never starts or ends a sentence, since this is something I consider bad style.

@ David Carlisle: I am aware of this. However, my workflow is to write each section as a separate document using LyX, and once I'm happy with the content, export the tex code and add it to my main document. Hence, unless you know a convenient method to configure LyX to use `\(`/`\)`, I'll stick with `$`/`$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Inserting a penalty after the math isn't so hard, see how the break after `$h$` is suppressed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

one two three $f$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six
one two three $h$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six
one two $g$ three $f$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six


\def\hmmm{\nolinebreak[3]}
\everymath{\aftergroup\hmmm}

one two three $f$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six
one two three $h$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six
one two $g$ three $f$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six
one two three $f$ four five six



\end{document}
```

Suppressing breaks before the math is likely to be fragile when using the `$` syntax most things you could think of would break something....